# Why does trying to click with selenium brings up "ElementNotInteractableException"?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on the webpage "https://2018.navalny.com/hq/arkhangelsk/" from the website's main page. However, I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

There's nothing after "Message:"

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://2018.navalny.com/')
time.sleep(5)
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'arkhangelsk')]")
type(linkElem)
linkElem.click()
```

I think xpath is necessary for me because, ultimately, my goal is to click not on a single link but on 80 links on this webpage. I've already managed to print all the relevant links using this :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'hq')]")
```

However, for starters, I'm trying to make it click at least a single link.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: It's because the element is not intractable when you click it. Since you're doing a sleep, this probably means the element is actually not intractable right then. Is this element actually visible on the page when you're trying to click it? If so, right click whatever it is you're trying to click on in chrome, and select 'inspect'. I'd put money on you finding that the actual element you're trying to click is different than what that xpath returns.

Comment: For what it's worth, your question leads me to believe that your selenium test is trying to be too clever(if you're writing this for the purpose of testing). In my opinion, automated UI tests should be very specific, and very deliberate in their execution. Finding all of the links and clicking all of them is a sign of a test that is too clever, and probably not useful in reporting the state of the product.

Comment: Which is that element you are referring by xpath as `//a[contains(@href,'arkhangelsk')]` on the UI?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure out issues like this, is to look at the page source using developer tools of your preferred browser. For instance, when I go to this page and look at HTML tab of the Firebug, and look for `//a[contains(@href,'arkhangelsk')]` I see this:

[image]

So the link is located within div, **which is currently not visible** (in fact entire sub-section starting from `div` with `id="hqList"` is hidden). Selenium will not allow you to click on invisible elements, although it will allow you to inspect them. Hence getting element works, clicking on it - does not.

What you do with it depends on what your expectations are. In this particular case it looks like you need to click on `<label class="branches-map__toggle-label" for="branchesToggle">Список</label>` to get that link visible. So add this:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Список").click();
```

after that you can click on any links in the list.

Comment: Hi Kiril, Thanks a lot for your comments, at the very least now I undestand why I could print the links but not click on them. However, when using the line of code you wrote, I get a "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Список" error. I'm not sure, but it feels like this could be due to the fact that list of cities is hidden behind a slider. (there's a map, and a list). Using "Карта" instead of "Список" doesn't bring up an error message (though it doesn't click either, since it's already on the webpage).