# Python - Splinter click

Tags: python, google-chrome, automation, click, splinter

I am trying to click on list item with below python script.

```
from splinter import Browser

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url ='https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/results?q=hemisphere+enhanced&k1=target&v1=Mars'
browser.visit(url)

browser.find_by_css("a.product-item").click()
```

and this gives me `WebDriverException` with below message. Any help please?

> Message: unknown error: Element `<a href="/search/map/Mars/Viking/cerberus_enhanced" class="itemLink product-item">...</a>` is not clickable at point (54, 228). Other element would receive the click: `<section id="results-accordian" class="block">...</section>`

Answer (score 0):

I am new but when I tried your code and get the same error. I went through the dev tools and it seems the element is not located properly thus confusing selenium.

this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590672/python-why-does-trying-to-click-with-selenium-brings-up-elementnotinteractabl?rq=1)